Attempt to invoke 'void io.capawesome.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.handlers.FacebookAuthProviderHandler.signIn on null object reference
Issue: I have implemented sign-in with Facebook in my Ionic Angular project using @capacitor-firebase/authentication. Below is the code I used:
import { FirebaseAuthentication } from '@capacitor-firebase/authentication';

async signInWithFacebook() {
  try {
    console.log("Calling FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithFacebook()");
    const result = await FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithFacebook();
    const user = result.user;
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error: ', error);
  }
}

Error: When I try to sign in, I get the following error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.capawesome.capacitorjs.plugins.firebase.authentication.handlers.FacebookAuthProviderHandler.signIn on a null object reference
Details: I have already completed all configurations related to Facebook and Firebase Console. Despite this, I am encountering the above error. Could anyone provide insight into why this might be occurring and how to resolve it?

i'm the maintainer of this package. It seems like you forgot to add facebook.com to the providers configuration array. Please make sure to follow the installation instructions correctly. Feel free to create a GitHub issue/discussion if you have more questions.

If i add facebook.com to the providers configuration array tha previous error is resolved, but when i try to sign-in i get below object and after that nothing happen, the process is being stopped. Why is that?
{
"callbackId": "119081414",
"pluginId": "FirebaseAuthentication",
"methodName": "signInWithFacebook",
"options": {}
}
Despite following all the installation instructions

Did you add the rgcfaIncludeFacebook project variable to your variables.gradle file (usually android/variables.gradle)?

Yes i added it.
This is my android/variable.gradle file
ext {
rgcfaIncludeFacebook = true
minSdkVersion = 22
compileSdkVersion = 34
.....
}

Something else is missing in this case. Please create a GitHub issue with a minimal, reproducible example and I'll take a look at it. Unfortunately, the information here is not enough to help you.
